# Sudden "MySQL server has gone away" error in PHP site

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, codeigniter

Today one of my websites started showing

```
Error Number: 2006
MySQL server has gone away
```

It's a low-traffic client site running under Apache 2.2.9 (Debian), PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny3 (using CodeIgniter 1.7.1 framework) and MySQL 5.0.51a. I obviously reasearched about the error but all the possible solutions imply that there are big queries going on that may time out and reset the connection, or hit the packet limits. However, this is not the case, it's a small database processed with the simplest queries. To be sure about this I made up a few  queries to return one row, still the same error.

Database credentials are fine, I can even login directly into mysql, run some of the site's queries and get the right data instantly. There are several other sites on the same server and connections to the database, much larger sites, and they all have no problems.

I tried:

- Restarting MySQL
- Restarting the whole server
- Looking for errors in the logs (both Apache and MySQL, none)
- Checking db user permissions
- Changing `mysql.connect_timeout` and `default_socket_timeout` in PHP
- Changing `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL
- Reading the [official docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html), forum and everything in SO that says "MySQL server has gone away"

**New:**

- Disabling persistent connections in PHP
- Changing `wait_timeout` and `connect_timeout` in MySQL

**Update:**

It seems to be related to the execution time of my script: it retrieves some info using the Facebook PHP client  and this call seems to be failing randomly today, so I either have no data from Facebook or the MySQL error. But to my surprise, none of the given solutions seems to deal with the timeout.

Any ideas? thank you for your time!

Comment: Are Apache and MySQL on the same box?  If you create a simple PHP page that runs a simple query (e.g. SELECT VERSION();) does that work?

Comment: @Eric J: Yes, and surprisingly for me, yes to the 2nd one too, it seems to be a problem carried by the framework then..

Comment: Any chance you could post the generated query output? I assume this is going through CodeIgniter. Are you using InnoDB or an exotic code page, by any chance?

Comment: @Pestilence Yeah I could but it's just some rows with not much ado. I'm using MyISAM and UTF-8 on all dbs/tables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said in my update, I concluded that the problem with MySQL arises when the link to Facebook takes longer than the maximum connection time with the DB. None of the suggestions could beat this limitation, so I decided to work around it and reconnect every time I presumed the link maybe gone.

So after each call to Facebook, I used to following code:

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->reconnect();
```

This is the particular solution when using CodeIgniter, and AFAIK the db->reconnect() function is only available since version 1.7.2 so I updated it in order to work.

Thanks everyone for your answers!

Comment: hi i have encountered this kind of problem and the solution is a change in the architecture of your website, you could never guarantee that facebook will reply in a definite time also the values/data taken from facebook will never be up to date. what we did is do a seperate chron job for fetching data from facebook

Comment: I have the same problem, and this doesn't work, did anything change since 2009 ?

Comment: I have a 500-point bounty here and am wondering if you think your experience is related and could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53469793/470749

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a connection time out affecting your persistent connections in PHP. I used to see them all of the time. The timeout parameter is within MySQL itself.

Your options include:
- not using persistent connections
- turning off idle timeout on the MySQL server
- trapping the error

I always wrap reconnection into my own PDO class, so I can't even remember if PHP reconnects or not. In any case, it's an easy fix. On query, catch & reconnect.

I have "generated" this error in the past with InnoDB. If you're using that engine, what's the output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` after a failure?

Comment: Disabling persistent connections didn't make any difference, but turning off idle timeout (zeroing MySQL's wait_timeout and connect_timeout, is that right?) seems to solve the issue. However, I'm afraid this might have negative repercussions, like never-ending MySQL processes, am I correct?
Also, what do you mean by "trapping the error"? I haven't done anything to the code, neither did the DB data changed, this is an overnight issue and that's the the weird thing.
Thank you!

Comment: Okay, the issue is still there, but I found a pattern. I'll update the question.

Comment: Zeroing mysql's timeouts can have negative repercussions on glitchy networks. Um, trapping the error would involve a bit of custom down in the DB handlers for your framework... or a giant catch (), connect and retry. Strange that disabling persistent connections didn't do the trick.

Comment: Actually... are you using replication on this MySQL box?

Comment: No, I did once just to migrate the server. I've updated the question, the culprit seems to be clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other sites work, we can assume that it is related to your site (and not the server). The official documents mention that this might happen if you try to execute queries after the server connection is closed. Do you have any hooks in CodeIgniter that does something towards the end of a request where the database connection might be closed?

Comment: No, I don't have any hooks in CodeIgniter or the DB

Answer (score 0):

You mention that this is an overnight task and that you're getting FaceBook data etc. Is the process running for a long time?

I've had a recent script that is moving data from one cluster to another and transforming formats etc. This script runs 24/7 moving this data across. I've found that with or without persistent connections, the MySQL libraries will still drop out after a few minutes (sometimes 5 minutes, sometimes longer).

The only way I've found to get around it for my case was to put a time check in my wrapper and to check how long it's been since the last time I reconnected before executing the query. I've set it to check if it's been greater than 2 minutes and if so, to reestablish the connection, ensuring to set the "new_link" flag (4th param) on mysql_connect is set to false.

Since changing this, I've never had the same error again.

Comment: Thank you for your input Lucas, but there was a misunderstanding, I meant that the problem was generated overnight, meaning it was sudden with no apparent cause. The task itself (the data retrieval and db stuff) is made in almost every page-load due to Facebook TOS.

Comment: Do you get the error instantly - ie as soon as you do a pageview? or are the cases where it fails after the script has been running a certain amount of time?

Comment: It may fail instantly or in the middle of the script, depending on the cause of the error. It's detailed in my answer now :)