# CodeIgniter mysqli real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am playing around with CodeIgniter 3 Dev and I keep getting this issue with MySQL.

```
mysqli::real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
```

Anyone else playing with CI 3 and happened to run into this and found a fix?

My work is local using wamp with a remote connection into a mysql server. I tried changing `php.ini`

```
mysqli.reconnect = Off
```

to

```
mysqli.reconnect = On
```

but it still pops up after an hour or two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sudden "MySQL server has gone away" error in PHP site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884111/sudden-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-in-php-site)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `core/My_Model.php`:

```
$this->db->reconnect();
```